# Printing an associative array inside a numerical array with PHP

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a numerical array for which each row is an associative array. A var_dump on this array is like :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
array (size=1)
  'brand' => string 'Daewoo' (length=6)
  1 => 
array (size=1)
  'brand' => string 'Honda' (length=5)
  2 => 
array (size=1)
  'brand' => string 'Mazda' (length=5)
```

How can I loop through this multi-dimensional array to show in a select/option the value of the key "brand" ?

I tried something like a for loop with a foreach loop inside but my associative array has no name, it's not declared as a variable.

Any idea ?

Comment: Google: `PHP array_column()`

Comment: Thanks for help, I didn't know about this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
foreach ($numerical_array AS $row) {
  print ("<option>" . $row['brand'] . "</option>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I always used a for loop on numerical array and foreach on associative array and didn't know I could use it like that.